# storybook web-components stencil static build

Tags: storybook, stenciljs

Building storybook stories for web components does not work. The stories are running only in development mode, but the built artifacts do not render.

After running `npm run build-storybook` and `python3 -m http.server` in the static output dir, this is the output.

[image]

The story code is the following:

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/web-components';

const meta: Meta = {
  component: 'my-component',
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj;

export const Example: Story = {
  args: {
    first: 'AAA',
    middle: 'BBB',
    last: 'CCC',
  }
}
```

For a more detailed report, see this [issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/25704).